# error: cannot find symbol method setInAppPurchaseListener(AdMobAdsAppPurchaseListener)

Tags: android, cordova, in-app-purchase, admob

I created a hybrid android app using cordova it was workin very fine before I add Google AdMob plugin.
After adding google AdMob plugin via the command line I am getting this error:

```
Error:(626, 23) error: cannot find symbol method setInAppPurchaseListener(AdMobAdsAppPurchaseListener)
```

I tried updating the SDK but nothing worked.

Note that I compile and run cordova app in android studio

[image]

Comment: Hello, I think you have enough exp. in StackOverflow to do not post code as image. Please post code snippet as text and full stacktrace

Comment: also post link to cordova plugin in github

Comment: Because you can't set an in app purchase listener on an ad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method was removed in version 11 of Admob ([source](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/adx/android/rel-notes)):

> Removed the getInAppPurchaseListener() and setInAppPurchaseListener() methods from the AdView, InterstitialAd, and NativeExpressAdView classes. Also removed related in-app purchase classes.

So it can't be found because you are using a version of the SDK that is >= version 11.0.0, which removed the methods.